# Failure to add a user for all origins

Tags: linux, mysql

When I try to add a new user with

```
grant all privileges on retrosias.* to 'rs3'@'%' identified by 'a';
```

I can't even connect locally :

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'rs3'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

If I add the same user using

```
grant all privileges on retrosias.* to 'rs3'@'localhost' identified by 'a';
```

then I can connect locally but my real need is to connect from any computer.

My server version is

```
Server version: 5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.04.3 (Ubuntu)
```

And I verified that users added before can still connect from anywhere (so not a firewall problem).

Where's my error ? Or what could be a workaround ?

Comment: Try "grant * on..." instead of "grant all privileges..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebooting the server did accomplish what neither `flush privileges` nor `service stop mysql` / `service start mysql` didn't.

All the (many) users I added before reboot are now accessible.

And the new users I add now with the same commands are accessible too.

I'm reluctant to accept my answer. I don't know if this is a known/frequent problem with mysql. The fact that I had to restart not only the service but also the whole computer is pretty disturbing.

Comment: I accepted this answer. But if somebody comes with a convincing bug report related to my problem, I'll be interested.

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql> select User,Host,Password from user;
+------+------------+-------------------------------------------+
| User | Host       | Password                                  |
+------+------------+-------------------------------------------+
| root | localhost  | *62395BB52702DE50773EBF629DD4AE90F07FFD94 |
| root | sgeorge-mn |                                           |
| root | 127.0.0.1  | *62395BB52702DE50773EBF629DD4AE90F07FFD94 |
| root | ::1        |                                           |
|      | localhost  |                                           |
|      | sgeorge-mn |                                           |
| suku | localhost  | *EAF5C8242B88A14545BB61062D64CA5207DD1A37 |
| rs3  | %          | *0FDB28C86F3804FCA60FA633DB4264B0EB169D9B |
| rs3  | localhost  | *667F407DE7C6AD07358FA38DAED7828A72014B4E |
+------+------------+-------------------------------------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

> It is necessary to have both `(% and localhost)` accounts for `rs3` to be able to connect
>   from anywhere as `rs3`. Without the localhost account, the
>   anonymous-user account for localhost that is created by
>   `mysql_install_db` would take precedence when `rs3` connects from the
>   localhost. As a result, `rs3` would be treated as an anonymous user.
>   The reason for this is that the anonymous-user account has a more
>   specific Host column value than the `'rs3'@'%'` account and thus comes
>   earlier in the user table sort order.

**About sort order:**

> The server uses sorting rules that order rows with the most-specific
>   Host values first. Literal host names and IP addresses are the most
>   specific. (The specificity of a literal IP address is not affected by
>   whether it has a netmask, so `192.168.1.13` and
>   `192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0` are considered equally specific.) The pattern **`'%'` means "any host" and is least specific**. The empty
>   string `''` also means "any host" but sorts after `'%'`. Rows with the
>   same Host value are ordered with the most-specific User values first
>   (a `blank User` value means "any user" and is least specific).

For more reading : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/adding-users.html

Comment: +1 for useful complementary information. Thanks.